# why ajax not work in this code

Tags: ajax

In callback of custom  menu  wrote function , in function I want to use node_add ,
I have a field that I want add AJAX to it, but when change the  field nothing happened 
where is the problem?
I am using Drupal 7

```
 module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = node_add('pre_register');
$form['field_course_display_ref']['und']['#value'][]=$nid;
    $form['field_course_display_ref']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'myfunction_ajax_change_course',
      'event' => 'change',
      'wrapper' => 'course-schedules-div',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    );
    $form['field_course_schedules']['#prefix'] = '<div id="course-schedules-div">';
    $form['field_course_schedules']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

I also try

```
 module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = node_add('pre_register');
$form['field_course_display_ref']['und']['#value'][]=$nid;
    $form['field_course_display_ref']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'myfunction_ajax_change_course',
      'event' => 'change',
      'wrapper' => 'course-schedules-div',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    );
    $form['field_course_schedules']['#prefix'] = '<div id="course-schedules-div">';
    $form['field_course_schedules']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

but nothing happened :(

**EDITED** I have two field, one `field_course_schedules` (will wrap) and `field_course_display_ref` The field that I want but changing it ajax will be trigger.

**type mistaked in code corrected but not worked again**

Comment: Reading [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784) should help

Comment: I read it before wrote this question , but I dont get my answer :(

Comment: Did you try something like `$form['field_course_display_ref']['und'][0]['value']['#ajax']` or `$form['field_course_display_ref']['und'][0]['target_id']['#ajax']` if it's an entity ref field?

Comment: @Clive I try them right now , but not work :(

Comment: are you sure there is a "checkbox-div" on the page?

Comment: @2pha yes, in main code I change div wrapper to `coruse-schedules-div`.

Comment: my problem is ajax not fire, I check console in firebug ,

Comment: ? but in the ['ajax']['wrapper'] it is checkbox-div.

Comment: @2pha I know,I change it but not work !!!

Comment: 1. Where are you including this code? What hook? Show us the function declaration (are you correctly getting the variables by reference and not by value?). 2. @2pha asked you whether an element with id:`checkboxes-div` is there on the webpage? So far we can only see that there's an element with id:`coruse-schedules-div`

Comment: I register a menu and in call back of menu I use this, notice the  code, I using `add_add` :|

Comment: and there is no typo in your div having `coruse` and everything else looking like `course`?

Comment: eg, you use `$form['field_coruse...']` to wrap your #prefix and #suffix, but use `$form['field_course...']` elsewhere....

Comment: @Jimajamma , sorry ,no every thing is course, it was type mistakes

Comment: so then elsewhere in your code you DO have a `$form['field_course_schedules']` that those #prefix/#suffix are added to, right?

Comment: @Jimajamma, sorry, I edit the post , please look at it agian, tnx

Comment: another oddity/typo is you are setting `$form['field_course_display_ref']['und']['#ajax']['wrapper']` to `course-schedules-div` yet in your print_r or other dump of the field it is saying it is `checkboxes-div`

Comment: @Jimajamma I dont edit print_r result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to modify a form which is already got built/processed!!

[node_add](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7) function is internally calling [drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) which will return the processed form, so even if you change anything it wont take any effect. i.e. Drupal will consider the things which are available when the form is being built/processed.

To overcome this you should use [drupal_retrive_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_retrieve_form/7) instead of [drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7).

The same problem is discussed [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42499/replace-default-submit-handler-when-using-drupal-get-form-in-d7) with different context, sadly the OP took part in that discussion :(

Comment: do u sure? my changes taked effrect in value and other attributes ,  `$form['field_user']['und'][0]['target_id']['#value']=$user->name.' ('.$user->uid.')';
        $form['field_user']['und'][0]['target_id']['#attributes']=array('disabled'=>'disabled') ;`  ???